# Why is my code not allowing me to add two object properties together in js?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, properties

I created a class called `product` which has `totalcost` as one of the properties. When the user presses 'add', the product will be added to an array called `products`. So, I am trying to add the totalcost of each object in the array to  get the sub total. But it only writes the code out the screen.

```
var subtotal = subtotal();

function subtotal() {
  if (products.length == 1) {
    subtotal = totalcost;
    return subtotal;
  } else if (products.length > 1) {
    for (i = 0; i < products.length; i++) {
      subtotal += products[i].totalcost + products[i + 1].totalcost;
      return subtotal;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: This doesn't look like java, it looks like js. Also, you haven't declared `i` or `subtotal` anywhere, which is an error in both languages

Answer (score -1, accepted):

please try following code for adding all the product total cost

```
function subtotal(){
var total=0;
    if(products.length == 1){
        total = totalcost;
        return total;
    }

    else if(products.length > 1){
        for(var i = 0; i<products.length; i++){
            total += products[i].totalcost;

    }
return total;
    }

    }
```

Comment: thank you. I just had to make a few edits with this and it works.

Answer (score 0):

I have created an example for you. you can use below code to get subtotal of list of **products**

```js
listproducts=[{totalcost:50},{totalcost:30},{totalcost:150}];
function FnSubtotal(products){
  subtotal=0;
  if(products.length == 0){
     return 0;
  }
  for(i = 0; i<products.length; i++){
      subtotal += products[i].totalcost;   
  }
  return subtotal;
};
console.log(FnSubtotal(listproducts))
```

Comment: The if block is unnecessary.